# Firebase retriggered with load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I'm using load() in a for cycle in order to generate a progressive list of element into my page(index), each one stored in a separate html file.
However it seems to retrigger the Firebase app I'm using, causing an infinite loop, and displaying the error: "firebase-app.js:26Uncaught Error: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists."

```
for(var i=0;i<8;i++){
   $('.prog-'+i).load("../projects/prog-id-"+array[i]+"/project.html").attr("id", "prog-id-"+array[i]);
};
```

PS. it works perfectly fine on localhost, it starts having these problem when I deploy the code.
PPS. The Firebase initialisation is technically not loaded twice as it's at the bottom of my index (the page where these contents are loaded)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `project.html` is pulling in Firebase each time, which leads to it being initialized multiple times. That explains the error.

You'll have to either load the Firebase dependency/initialization separately and only once OR you can detect whether Firebase has already been initialized with something like:

```
var exists = false;
firebase.apps.forEach(function(app) {
  if (app.name == '[DEFAULT]') {
    exists = true;
  }
})
if (!exists) firebase.initializeApp(...);
```